# How to use Css selector to locate 1 element by using 2 contributes at the same time in Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Python Css selector to locate 1 element by 2 contributes at the same,and both contribute need to be partial.

Now I can locate this element by Xpath successfully:

```
fifth_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[contains(@id, 'coption') and @style='display: block;']")
```

The id and style value are both partial,when I tired:

```
fifth_item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id*='coption')][style*='display: block;']")
```

Failed

The html code is here:

```
<div id="coption5" class="copt" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: Yes,sir,just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below css

```
fifth_item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id ^='coption')][style='display: block;']")
```

**Note: please take care of Double and single quote as I am typing from Mobile keypad**

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,but the id value is also a partial value ,should I use: fifth_item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div*#coption[style='display: block;']")  ?

Comment: Yes if it is contains ‘coption’

Comment: @William  please try edited solution and please let me know style attribute has full value or partial

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,both id and style attribute have partial value.

Comment: Ok then please try the solution with ‘contains’

Comment: I think if you can share html of div would help us

Comment: One more thing double quote “ and single quote ‘ will not be correct as i m typing with mobile keypad

Comment: Now you can try